# echarts dataZoom event does not return timestamp but only percentages

Tags: javascript, echarts

I got a chart with a dataZoom component. The x-axis is of type `time`.
Zooming and roaming the chart works perfectly. But when I listen for the `dataZoom` event to hook into the zooming process I only get percentage values (0-100) from the event as current position.

the dataZoom config:

```
dataZoom: {
   start: 0,
   end: 3,
   showDetail: false
}
```

my xAxis config:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    boundaryGap: false,
    splitLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
            color: '#ddd',
            type: 'dashed'
        }
    },
    axisLine: {
        show: false
    }
},
```

I listen for the event like this:

```
myChart.on('dataZoom', function (evt) {
  console.log('zoom', evt);
})
```

And I get this console output for `evt`:

```
{
  "type": "datazoom",
  "from": "viewComponent_17_0.8229841241707196",
  "dataZoomId": "\u0000\u0000-\u00000",
  "start": 1.6141473287753287,
  "end": 11.178346465795
}
```

I would expect it to be something like:

```
"start" : "2012-12-01 15:30:00Z",
"end" : "2012-12-01 15:40:00Z"
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
myChart.on('datazoom', function (evt) {
  var axis = myChart.getModel().option.xAxis[0];
  var starttime = axis.data[axis.rangeStart];
  var endtime = axis.data[axis.rangeEnd];
  console.log(starttime,endtime);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently you don't get it from the event.
There is an issue connected to this: [4906](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/issues/4906)

A work around is to get the value from getOption like this:

```
const { startValue, endValue } =  echart.getEchartsInstance().getOption().dataZoom[0]
```

You can do this in your on dataZoom event handler (instead of using the values in the evt)

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem the following simple code works perfectly for me:

```
myChart.on('dataZoom', function() {
  var option = myChart.getOption();
  console.log(option.dataZoom[0].startValue, option.dataZoom[0].endValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to retrieve the timestamps on the datazoom. I wanted to retrieve the zoomed period as well as the full period. Eventually I found that I does not need to get it during **dataZoom** event. As long as the echarts is initialized, you can call the following function to retrieve the 4 main timestamps from the chart.

```js
getChartDateRange() {
    const option = myChart.getOption().dataZoom[0],
        m = (option.endValue - option.startValue) / (option.end - option.start),
        fullStartValue = m * (0 - option.start) + option.startValue,
        fullEndValue = m * (100 - option.start) + option.startValue;
    return {
        fullStart: 0,
        fullEnd: 100,
        fullStartValue: fullStartValue,
        fullEndValue: fullEndValue,
        zoomStart: option.start,
        zoomEnd: option.end,
        zoomStartValue: option.startValue,
        zoomEndValue: option.endValue
    };
}
```