# Getting values instead of percentages of dataZoom in Apache Echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using Apache Echarts, and I have a chart with an X axis of type `time`, with a dataZoom of type `slider`. This serves as an example:

```js
var values = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    values.push([date, i])
}

const firstDate = values[1][0];
const lastDate = values[5][0];

option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        boundaryGap: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
    },
    dataZoom: [{
        type: 'slider',
    }],
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: values, 
        }
    ]
};

myChart.on('datazoom', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
})
```

In the event I receive 'start' and 'end' as percentages, but what I would like to receive are **the actual start and end date**. This means, the values of the axis itself.

I checked [the docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datazoom), and they say that I can actually get the values when "zoom event of triggered by toolbar". I am not sure whether this refers to the toolbox datazoom (which does not fulfill my needs) or any other thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As F.Marks answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402606/2741235), you should get the values in dataZoom echart`s option property object like the code below:

```js
myChart.on('dataZoom', function() {
  var option = myChart.getOption();
  console.log(option.dataZoom[0].startValue, option.dataZoom[0].endValue);
});
```

Comment: option.dataZoom[0].startValue (or endValue) return the respective index in the series or xAxis data. So the code to get the actual value will be like:  
  
```option.series.find(s => s.id == 'finded_series_id').data[option.dataZoom[0].startValue]```

or for the xAxis:  
  
```option.xAxis[index].data[option.dataZoom[0].startValue]```